# Delete webAPI not working for release mode apk

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, http-delete

I have developed an android app using Web API. I'm deleting a row using `HttpDelete` through .NET Web API. App working perfect on debug mode. But as I published the signed release mode apk, the app gets crash on delete Web API.
Please provide me the solution for it.
Attaching code of android for delete

```
private class DeleteData extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        int id = params[0];

        Log.d("got id",""+id);
        try {

            URL url = new URL("My URL");

            Log.d("URL",""+url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            int byteCharacter;
            String result="";
            while ((byteCharacter = is.read()) != -1)
            {
                result += (char)byteCharacter;
            }
            Log.d("json api",result);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MORJ6.jpg)

Comment: Do you perhaps have any crash logs?

Comment: @archLucifer working fine on debug mode but crashes on release apk so dont have any error logs

Comment: Please post your App Gradle file

Comment: @archLucifer please check the image attached

Comment: Without crash logs it is hard to tell, but your proguard rules are most likely ommiting your classes required that's why it is crashing. Try adding the following in your proguard file. 

-keep class java.net.** and 
-keep interface java.net.**